# Creating a route using mapquest webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services, mapquest

I'm trying to create a route using the map mapquest on android, and I'm trying to create using the webservice the mapquest, because you need to make a reference, is a key enterprise, I have the following code.

```
URL url = new URL("http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=MY_KEY&callback=renderAdvancedNarrative&outFormat=json&routeType=fastest&timeType=1&enhancedNarrative=false&shapeFormat=raw&generalize=0&locale=en_US&unit=m&from=-20.64,-47.28&to=-23.4,-46.32&drivingStyle=2&highwayEfficiency=21.0");

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "MY_REFERER");

InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

String str = IOUtils.toString(input, "utf-8");

input.close();

JSONObject test = new JSONObject(str.replace("renderAdvancedNarrative(", "").replace(")", ""));

RouteResponse response = new RouteResponse(test);

listShapes = response.route.shape.shapePoints;
```

This code, me returns data in JSON format, returns me the coordinates.

```
response.route.shape.shapePoints
```

This code returns an array of GeoPoints

The problem is that I am unable to find a way to create the route of such information that I have.

Could anyone help me solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try using https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android  This project allows you to calculate the route between two locations and displays it on a map.

Comment: But I'm not using the google map, I'm using the mapquest, it affects something in this api? Or works both maps?

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

As I was not finding one solution , I tried another way to create a route without mapquest map using webservice with a key enterprise .

```
URL url = new URL("http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=MY_KEY&callback=renderAdvancedNarrative&outFormat=json&routeType=fastest&timeType=1&enhancedNarrative=false&shapeFormat=raw&generalize=0&locale=en_US&unit=m&from=-20.64,-47.28&to=-23.4,-46.32&drivingStyle=2&highwayEfficiency=21.0");

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "MY_REFERER");

InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

String str = IOUtils.toString(input, "utf-8");

input.close();

JSONObject test = new JSONObject(str.replace("renderAdvancedNarrative(", "").replace(")", ""));

RouteResponse response = new RouteResponse(test);

// HERE

Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 187, 248));
paint.setAlpha(100);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeWidth(13);

LineOverlay line = new LineOverlay(paint);
line.setData(response.route.shape.shapePoints);
line.setKey("Line #1");

this.mapOver.getOverlays().add(line);
this.mapOver.invalidate();
```

It is certainly not the best way to do , but for me it worked .

Thank you .

- EDIT

Added the supplement , so that the map is centered according to the coordinates .

```
int middleArray = Math.round(list.size() / 2);
this.mapOver.getController().setCenter(list.get(middleArray));
```

- EDIT

Remembering that this line of code is a security breach , but it is the meneira of how mapquest uses to refer to a key interprise .

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "MY_REFERER");
```